# What the difference about vector initialize

Tags: c++11, initializer-list

I have read some about C++11 initialize list, uniform initialize, and some others. But I still has some confuse about their difference. Please kindly check below and what the difference among them. Thanks!

```
std::vector<int> a1({1, 2, 3, 4});
// this is initialize list a object, then copy-constructor? 

std::vector<int> a2{1, 2, 3, 4};
// this is initialize list

std::vector<int> a2{{1, 2, 3, 4}};
// what is this?
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you think you understand and what doesn't make sense to you? Without details any answer will look just the same as those other things you have already read. And if those didn't help you likely any generic answers also won't help you. So for a useful answer you'd have to describe your difficulties better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> a1({1, 2, 3, 4});

std::vector<int> a2{1, 2, 3, 4};

std::vector<int> a2{{1, 2, 3, 4}};
```

All 3 lines do the same thing :

The compiler creates an `std::initializer_list<int>` then passes it to the constructor of `std::vector<int>` which takes an `std::initializer_list<int>`.

Comment: I think the question is if a copy construction happens when the temporary `initializer_list` is passed to the constructor of `vector`. I think it's a move in this case.

Comment: @isarandi Well since `std::initializer_list` does not own its content, and as said in [its corresponding cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) it "may be implemented as a pair of pointers or pointer and length", the move and copy of an `std::initializer_list` are most likely the exact same operation (few pointer/integer assignations).